# Docker Swarm - indicate a container is busy and shouldn't be terminated?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, windows-container

This may be an odd question, and I suspect the answer is a resounding "no, this isn't possible", but I'd rather ask anyway.

I've got a Docker Swarm setup running some Windows containers with DevOps Agents for our CI/CD needs. This is all nice and well. The problem is if I want to update the images I'm using on these containers. At the moment I need to:

1. Disable all agents belonging to a particular Docker host in our DevOps Server (on-prem)
2. Wait for any queued jobs to finish (if there are any)
3. Restart the stack / service with a new image + enable all the agents in DevOps

Ideally I'd like to just queue up the image update for the Docker service and let that handle everything. Alas, if I did so now Docker would just kill the containers one by one with complete disregard for any running jobs. And the problem is point #2 can sometimes take a lot of time.

Is it possible to somehow have a container inform Docker that it is "busy" and shouldn't be terminated?

Comment: AFAIK, your container process is sent a SIGKILL when Docker wants it to terminate. I'd explore if it's possible to intercept that and only terminate when the job is finished.

Comment: @HansKilian There's an open issue re. [how Windows containers are closed](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25982) which has been open since 2016... Thus I don't think this will get resolved any time soon and, subsequently, I don't think reacting to the termination signal is a viable way of going forward with this. Finally, remember I'm dealing with Windows containers - so it won't, technically, be SIGKILL. ;)

Comment: Could you tackle this in the other direction, and equip each container with a quit API (e.g. over HTTP)? That way it can exit if it is ready to do so, or send a reject response, and the caller should retry. That does mean that your upgrade operation needs more home-made pieces, but perhaps that's the price you pay for this flexibility.

Comment: Or the quit API could record the quit request and exit the container once the current job is finished. Indeed it could hang onto the HTTP operation and return minutes later with a response (leaving the caller hanging deliberately).

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure how that could be done. I mean, at the end of the day I've got "limited" control over the containers, since they aren't started manually but rather as a Docker Swarm service, meaning Docker itself is managing them and I can only manage the containers via docker. I COULD, technically, create some tool that detects if a given agent is busy or not, sure, but the key question is how would Docker then use this information to prevent Docker from tearing down said container?

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Alright, just riffing here with an example: set up a service with a replica count of two, each on version 0.1, then bump up the image to version 0.2. The two running instances will still be on 0.1. Then send an API signal to one of them to quit when it is ready, and then (I assume) Swarm will try to start a new one based on the dropped replica count. Would the new instance be at v0.1 or 0.2? (in other words does it start by image name or image hash?)

Comment: @halfer AFAIK the only way is to perform `docker service update <service> --image <image>`, but that, in turn, will trigger a rolling update. There's a `--update-parallelism` parameter, but setting this to `0` will just update all containers at once. So I'm not sure how I can "just" *bump the image version*.

Comment: Sure, that's a manual operation. But what happens if a parallelism of two has one task end naturally (as part of your container design). Does Swarm not spin up a replacement, so the parallelism is maintained?

Comment: @halfer Docker Swarm spins a new container when an old one is stopped, yes. But AFAIK it won't update the version on its own, even when using `:latest`. And updating the image => rolling update => docker stops containers. Unless I'm not understanding your idea?

Comment: Ah right - I think you understood my idea, and it would not work. Alright, while I am in danger of sending lots of half-baked ideas, here is another. On your Docker host, you could have a service to which you send an "upgrade available" message (e.g. via an HTTP API). In turn this notifies your container(s) to exit once they are done with their existing workloads. Finally this service would periodically scan for a missing container and recreate it with the upgraded version. For the avoidance of doubt, this does not use replication tricks - it does it all manually.

Comment: If you want you could ensure that your containers would only exit at 2am when you are not working. (As a bonus, you could create a container to do all this logic - just share the Docker socket from host to container as a volume, and then you can put all of this logic in a new container.)

Answer (score -1):

Docker service update has the following flag:
`--stop-grace-period duration         Time to wait before force killing a container (ns|us|ms|s|m|h)`
which is mirrored in compose/stack yaml:
[stop_grace_period](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#stop_grace_period)

Whether or not this works (and how) on windows remains an open question.

tl;dr don't use windows containers.

Comment: The last sentence is annoying me beyond belief. Please tell me how would you propose I handle DevOps build agents capable or VsBuild or other Windows-centric operations?

Comment: Have a high tolerance for being annoyed beyond belief. Windows containers are huge, with consequently long startup times. require an exact match to the windowsservercore and consequently base OS version, making applying security upgrades ... fraught, and require apps that only use a subset of the windows api available in containers.

Comment: I'm not arguing Windows containers are somehow great. My point is I cannot NOT use them (unless you have an idea on how to run `VSBuild@1` in a non-Windows container without a VS install). So the argument "don't use Windows containers" is, quite frankly, useless and unhelpful.